# How store xml file special characters values in its as it is?

Tags: php, xml

I am using my xml file to store special chars.

This is my original file

```
<root>
  <popups>
        <popup id="1">
            <text1>
                <![CDATA[dynamic text popup 2a]]>
            </text1>
            <text2>
                <![CDATA[dynamic text popup 2b]]>
            </text2>
         </popup>
     </popups>
</root>
```

Now when I use php to save special chars eg , it becomes like that

```
<root>
    <popups>
        <popup id="1">
            <text1>&lt;![CDATA[Hello world]]&gt;</text1>
            <text2>&lt;![CDATA[asassa]]&gt;</text2>
        </popup>
    </popups>
</root>
```

I have used the following code :

```
$this->xmlDocument = simplexml_load_file("xml/conf.xml");
    $pages_node = $this->xmlDocument->xpath("/root/popups/popup[@id=1]");

    $name = $_POST['popup-name'];
    $editor1 = trim(strip_tags($_POST['editor1']));
    $editor2 = trim(strip_tags($_POST['editor2']));
    if (!empty($name)){
        if (!empty($editor1)){ 
            $pages_node[0]->text1 = "<![CDATA[".$editor1."]]>"; 
        }
        if (!empty($editor2)){ 
            $pages_node[0]->text2 =  "<![CDATA[".$editor2."]]>" ;
        }
        $this->xmlDocument->asXml($this->basePath() . "conf/conf.xml");
    }
```

How can I save the special chars as they are without needing to encode them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplexml is meant to be simple, so there is no such option. `dom_import_simplexml` can help you create `domdocument` from simplexml object.

You have to create new instance of DOMDocument, then create CDATA section and put it into imported DOMElement node.

If you are using php `DomDocument`, you have to create [DOMCDATASection](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php) and append it to text1/text2 nodes.

If you don't have `text1` and `text2` nodes, you have to create them first, then appencd cdata node to them and finally append them to `popup`:

```
$cdata = $dom->createCDATASection("test");

$text1 = $dom->createElement('text1');
$text1->appendChild($cdata);

$text1 = $dom->createElement('text2');
$text2->appendChild($cdata);

$popupNode->appendChild($text1);
$popupNode->appendChild($text2);
```